# Mongodb findOne with or

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my example i have a login view email or username can send one of two.

```
User.findOne({ 'email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
// awesome user
});
```

and i need something like this:

```
User.findOne({ 'email' :  email } || {'username' :  email}, function(err, user) {
// awesome user
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Can do using the [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query operator:

```
User.findOne({$or: [{'email': email}, {'username': email}]}, function(err, user) {
    // awesome user
});
```